# Optimization Algorithm: Find Closest List from Array of Lists

Tags: algorithm, math, graph, statistics, mathematical-optimization

I have a dataset listing 12-month average temperatures for cities, e.g. (in Fahrenheit)

```
{"Paris" : [45,47,54,60,67,73,77,77,70,61,51,46] },
{"London" : [48,49,53,58,65,70,74,73,67,60,53,48] },
{"Istanbul" : [48,49,53,62,71,79,83,83,77,68,59,51] },
..
```

My goal is, for any given city, find the top N closest equivalents (maybe the candidates should be made non-local for better results, as in Lat/Lon+1 away, but this can be tweaked later).

"Top N Equivalents" is defined as:

1) Year-Round -- the minimum per-month deviation from source for all 12 months

2) Seasonal -- the minimum per-month deviations from source for months (4-6) (Spring), (7-9) (Summer), (10-12) (Autumn), (1-3) (Winter).

In other words, the goal of this algorithm is to reveal which intercontinental cities share climatic similarities.

Math isn't my strong suit; is this a Graph Optimization problem, or a root-mean-square optimization? I can find all the per-month differences for every city, but what do I do then?

Comment: You sum them up (e.g. their absolute values or their squares) and pick the smallest.

Comment: So is it the absolute values or the squares?

Comment: Your decision. Depends on how you want to measure deviation.